# Whats wrong with my function code (MATLAB/OCTAVE)

Tags: matlab, function, octave

I am trying to make my program work.  It is for prime numbers.

Below is my function then my main program

I believe this is the right formatting, (obviously I'm probably wrong cause its not working) and I have been trying to fix it to no avail.  Any help will be most appreciated and an explanation of what I am doing wrong (I am pretty sure it has to do with subtle formatting) would be great too.

```
function [answer,primefactors ] = primey1 (N)
for i=2:(N-1)
    A(i-1)=rem(N,i);
end
A;
if(all(A)==1)
    answer=['Yes']
    primefactors=[1,N]
elseif(all(A)==0)
    answer=['No']
    fac=[]
    for i=2:N
        q=0;
        while N/i==floor(N/i)
            N=N/i;
            q=q+1;
        end
        if q>0
            fac=[fac,i]
            if N==1
                break
                primefactors=[fac]
            end
        end
    end
end

endfunction
```

Comment: the main program function i use is:

N = 15485863;
[answer,primefactors] = primey1(N);
fprintf('Is %i a prime? %s \n', N, answer)
fprintf('The primefactors of %i are: \n' , N)
fprintf('%i \n' , primefactors)

Comment: Well for starters... it is not well formatted

Comment: Can you explain this: "*cause its not working*" in a little more detail, please? Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: what is it trying to do? I do not want to have to try to interpret what the code is doing and find something wrong with it.

Comment: i try different things to tweak it and it says either along the lines of there is an error with the output (its as if the output does not exist).  and the program is to determine if the value N is a prime number or not and if it is, what its prime factors are.

Comment: it worked when i made it without the function command, but when try and make it into a function file is where I get all my problems.

Comment: If you run your original code outside the function file preceded by `clear all`, you will find that if the number is not prime the variables will not exist in the end. Worse even, if you start without clear you may end up with the wrong result.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by Magla, MATLAB comes with the `primes` and `factor` functions, which you can at least use to compare your implementation with and/or check your outcomes.

Anyway, as for your code, try this:

```
function [answer, primefactors] = primey1(N)

    % Use vectorization for simple cases such as these: 
    A = rem(N,2:N-1);

    if all(A)
        answer = 'Yes';
        primefactors = [1,N];

    % Re-wrote this entire section. There were a bunch of things wrong with it: 
    % the order of commands was wrong, variables were not assigned for some N, 
    % etc. Just compare the two implementations
    else
        answer = 'No';        
        primefactors = [];

        for ii = 2:N

            q = 0;            
            while N/ii == floor(N/ii)
                N = N/ii;
                q = q+1;
            end

            if q > 0
                primefactors = [primefactors,ii]; %#ok<AGROW>
                if N==1                   
                    break;
                end
            end

        end

    end

end
```

Comment: The key factor to "solving" the issue with the code in the question is to understand, why it claims that the output is not defined. And as Rody showed, it is because you set it *after* you break.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has a `factor` function that does what your code is trying to do

```
p = factor(10)
```

returns 2, 5
and

```
p = factor(11)
```

returns 11.

All you have is to test for `length`

```
if length(p) == 1
```

is `true` for prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The solution as offered by @Rody should do the job, in theory even more efficient than this, however to illustrate the concept of initialization, I would recommend you to initialize the output variables of your function right after the function start. In your case this would mean that I recommend starting the code like this:

```
function [answer, primefactors] = primey1(N)
% Function to determine whether a number is prime and which prime factors it has

% Assign default values
answer = 'No';
primefactors = [];
```